# Embed facebook social timeline in a website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Can I embed facebook/Instagram timeline on my website, something like [Twitter Embedded User Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/user)? For Facebook, I can see [activity feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity) in the older version(before 2.3) of Graph API, but this is now deprecated. Are there any other alternatives for this?

Comment: For public Facebook pages you can use the Page plugin; for user profiles there is no such thing.

Comment: @CBroe I need it for profiles. Any workarounds you can suggest?

Comment: You can not get a user timeline via API, at most you can get their own posts (after they log in to your app, and grant it the appropriate permission.)